# Ring of polynomials

Tags: ring-theory

Let F be a field and R = F [X], the ring of polynomials over F . Show that

$$R^X=F^X$$,the set of non-zero constant polynomials.

I am having a little trouble first understanding the question 
hence i clearly cant solve it.

I would appreciate any help in first what the question is asking and if you could provide proof with an explanation i would be grateful to you

Thanks

Comment: It might help if you could say where you saw this.

Comment: So the $X$ in $R^X$ has nothing to do with the $X$ in $F[X]$?  Usually the nonzero constant polynomials (i.e. units) are denoted $R^{\times}$ or $R^*$.

Comment: @tylerc0816 Ah, so *that's* what OP meant! I was honestly completely baffled by what was written. The problem is to show that the multiplicative groups of units coincide, if your guess is correct (which seems very likely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've written an $X$ where you shouldn't have.  The problem is to show that $R^\times$ (*not* $R^X$!), the group of invertible elements of $R$, equals $F^\times$, the group of invertible (i.e. nonzero) elements of $F$ (considered as constant polynomials).

You should solve this problem in two steps:

1. Show that any nonzero constant polynomial has an inverse.  This isn't hard, but you should make sure to write a clear proof of it anyway, as a warm-up.
2. Show that any non-constant polynomial cannot have a multiplicative inverse.  In other words if $f$ and $g$ are two polynomials, and $f(x)g(x) = 1$, then $f$ and $g$ must both be constants. This should be intuitively clear, but if you cannot figure out how to make the argument rigorous, then here is hint: consider the terms of highest degree that appear in each of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: appreciate the help on second step say if f=1/x and g=x then fg=1 so ff and g need not be constant? please clarify this for me and thanks again

Comment: @Jam $1/x$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: $x^-1$ is a polynomial where -1 belongs to Z

Comment: @Jam That is not what a polynomial is.

Comment: my brain is malfunctioning of course it is not Thanks for help